# how to concatenate two formatted strings in python

Tags: python, string, printing, concatenation, formatted-text

Is there a way to concatenate these two formatted strings horizontally? I tried a + b but am having a vertically concatenated strings.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjHnD.png) is a screen shot of the formatted strings.

```
a =  '''
      __  
     (  ) 
      )(  
     (__) 
   '''
b = '''
    ____ 
   (  __)
    ) _) 
   (__) 
  '''
 print(a+b) #I don't need this I need horizontal way of concatenation
```

Comment: You have to concatenate line by line

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please include your sample code as text in your question, not as a picture or link, to make a [mcve]

Comment: how can I concatenate line by line? @dcg

Comment: If the strings are multi-line, then a simple `a + b` will not work.  You'll have to separate each string into lines, then concatenate each corresponding line from a and b.

Comment: Thanks, I have included the code @G.Anderson

Comment: oh that will be a lot of work if am dealing with a more complex strings. Any other way? @JohnGordon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar to this

```
>>> lines = zip(a.split('\n'), b.split('\n'))
>>> ab = '\n'.join([ai + bi for ai, bi in lines])
>>> print ab

      __      ____ 
     (  )    (  __)
      )(      ) _) 
     (__)    (__) 

>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @dcg

Comment: You can also use `map` in place of `zip`, with the help of `operator.add`: `'\n'.join(map(add, a.split('\n'), b.split('\n')))`. One may or may not consider that an improvement :)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate line by line as follows.

```
c = [x + y for x, y in zip(a.split('\n'), b.split('\n'))] 
# x + y is line by line concatenation
# zip is selecting a pair of lines at a time from a & b

print('\n'.join(c))
```

**Output**

```
  __      ____ 
 (  )    (  __)
  )(      ) _) 
 (__)    (__)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A straight answer could be simple if we define the two formatted strings using 'arrays'. The answer is:

```
aa = ["___"],["()"],[")("]
bb = ["___"],[")("],["()"]
print (aa)
print (bb)

cc=[]
for index in range(3):
   cc.append(aa[index]+ bb[index])

print (cc[0][0], cc[0][1])
print (cc[1][0], cc[1][1])
print (cc[2][0], cc[2][1])
```

The formatted strings are different from the example but we hope that the concept is clear.

Result:

[image]